# Retrieve transaction details using Payment Resource in Paypal

Tags: php, rest, cakephp, paypal

What I want to do:
Use Cakephp's httpsocket class and retrieve the payment details of a transaction.

What I have tried:

```
    $HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
    $request = array(
        'header' => array(
            'Authorization' => 'Basic QVh5TEhoRERjUVZQb1JicV93UXlJb21ublo4N3p2RWozMWXXXX1tS2pDNmdtSlVwOWZ5TG5yZ0s4Y2F5Og=='
            )
        );
    $results = $HttpSocket->post('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token', 'grant_type=client_credentials', $request);
    $results_array = json_decode($results, TRUE);

    $request2 = array(
        'header' => array(
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$results_array['access_token']
            )
        );
    $results2 = $HttpSocket->get('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXXXXXXXXX93349KRAPLNI', array(), $request2);

    echo $results2;
```

What I have got:

Of the 1st Post request that I make, I get proper result in json format which has the scope, access_token, expires_in etc

`$results = $HttpSocket->post('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token', 'grant_type=client_credentials', $request);`

But when I pass the access token to the 2nd request, i.e GET, I get Unauthorized Access Error

```
$results2 = $HttpSocket->get('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXXXXXXXXX93349KRAPLNI', array(), $request2);
```

I dont know what i am doing wrong. Maybe not setting the headers right..I'm not sure.

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated. If I am missing out on any details/code, please feel free to ask, i'll post them in comments.

Comment: Have you solved this ? Did you set a fake payment details post data with your call? The second call should be a post too. Your headers are fine but the buyer info should be posted too.

Refrence: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/

Comment: Yes. I was able to solve this.
I was setting wrong header in     
`$request = array(
        'header' => array(
            'Authorization' => 'Basic QVh5TEhoRERjUVZQb1JicV93UXlJb21ublo4N3p2RWozMWXXXX1tS2pDNmdtSlVwOWZ5TG5yZ0s4Y2F5Og=='
            )
        );`
So as a result, I was getting invalid access_token, and thus unauthorized error
A stupid copy paste error by me..